# UIImageView fails to update repeatedly

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a view controller, which calls the following in viewDidAppear:

```
[self updateCameraImage];
[cameraImageView setImage:lastCameraImage];
```

That works great. In the background, the updateCameraImage method sends a message to the server and retrieves image data, then converts that data to a UIImage. It then sets self.lastCameraImage to this UIImage. The second line set this image to cameraImageView.image and the new image shows on screen. This UIImageView was added in a storyboard and added to the header as a property.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *lastCameraImage;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *cameraImageView;
```

I would like this to continually update. The problem is that if I do something like the following, it doesn't actually show a new image in the view until the last time setImage is called. I know the image is being retrieved, so I can't tell why it's not working.

```
[self updateCameraImage];
[cameraImageView setImage:lastCameraImage];
[self updateCameraImage];
[cameraImageView setImage:lastCameraImage];
[self updateCameraImage];
[cameraImageView setImage:lastCameraImage];
```

Any help would be great! Thanks.

Comment: Use NSTimer, as i know Apple has set it to not update visuals when written like that, like in a loop statement or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running this code on the main thread, and your `updateCameraImage` function is synchronous, then you'll be blocking the UI until all code completes. Try performing the fetch in the background, then dispatch back to the main thread to update the UI.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    [self updateCameraImage];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [cameraImageView setImage:lastCameraImage];
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! That did it. I added a few calls back to the main queue to update UI with progress. Do you happen to know a good resource to read up on background queues and interactions with UI? This makes keeping track of state much tougher.

Comment: Nothing specific comes to mind but I'm sure a quick Google search should yield some interesting information. Bottom line is you want to do any long running code in the background, and UIKit code should be run on the main thread. Good luck :)